# How can i speed up data labelling for a large pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large pandas data frame which roughly looks this

```
  Identity  periods      one        two       three     Label
0   one      1       -0.462407    0.022811  -0.277357
1   one      1       -0.617588    1.667191  -0.370436
2   one      2       -0.604699    0.635473  -0.556088
3   one      2       -0.852943    1.087415  -0.784377
4   two      3        0.421453    2.390097   0.176333
5   two      3       -0.447321   -1.215280  -0.187156
6   two      4        0.398953   -0.334095  -1.194132
7   two      4       -0.324348   -0.842357   0.970825
```

I need to be able to categorise the data according to groupings in the various columns, for example one of my categorisation criteria is to label each of the groups in the identity column with a label if there is between x and y periods in the periods column.

The code I have to categorise this looks like this, generating a final column:

```
for i in df['Identity'].unique():
    if (2 <= df[df['Identity']==i]['periods'].max() <= 5) :
        df.loc[df['Identity']==i,'label']='label 1'
```

I have also tried a version using

`df.groupby('Identity').apply().`

But this is no quicker.

My data is approximately 2.8m rows at the moment, and there are about 900 unique identities. The code takes about 5 minutes to run, which to me suggests it's the code within the loop that is slow, rather than the looping making it slow.

Comment: Are all of the labels based on the `max` value of period within group, if not what is the logic for the other labels...

Comment: Two of the labels are based on the max value of period within group, but I have another label which is based on the number of unique values in one of the data columns. It appears that this first example is the most computationally exhaustive at the moment, so I should be able to make most of the gains by tackling this one first!

my second label currently looks like:

df[df['Identity']==i]['one'].round().unique() > 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try to enhance the system performance by using all vectorized Pandas operations instead of using loops or `.apply()` function which is also just commonly using the relatively slow Python loops internally.

Use `.groupby()` and `.transform()` to broadcast `max()` of `periods` within group to get a series for making mask.  Then use `.loc[]` with the mask of the condition 2 <= max <=5 and setup label for such rows fulfulling the mask.

Assumed same label for all rows of same `Identity` group whenever the max period within the group is within 2 <= max <=5.

```
m = df.groupby('Identity')['periods'].transform('max')
df.loc[(m >=2) & (m <=5), 'Label'] = 'label 1'


print(df)

  Identity  periods       one       two     three    Label
0      one        1 -0.462407  0.022811 -0.277357  label 1
1      one        1 -0.617588  1.667191 -0.370436  label 1
2      one        2 -0.604699  0.635473 -0.556088  label 1
3      one        2 -0.852943  1.087415 -0.784377  label 1
4      two        3  0.421453  2.390097  0.176333  label 1
5      two        3 -0.447321 -1.215280 -0.187156  label 1
6      two        4  0.398953 -0.334095 -1.194132  label 1
7      two        4 -0.324348 -0.842357  0.970825  label 1
```

Comment: Thank you SeaBean! This is great, it worked perfectly. I replaced two of my label criteria with your solution.

The final label criteria I had to modify slightly, and came up with m=df.round(0).groupby('Identity')['one'].transform('nunique')

The outcome is that a block of code that took 7 minutes to run now takes 5 seconds, thanks for the time you took to help.